# UIImageView disappears after adding another UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard

I have this code:

```
    secondImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.gif"]];
    [secondImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(148, 192, 126, 142)];
    secondImageView.alpha = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:secondImageView];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"pfeilNachRechtsUndsecondNachVorne" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:4.0];
    secondImageView.alpha = 1;
    [firstImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(47, 192, 93, 142)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

The `firstImageView` is added in the interface builder and I want to add the second one programmatically. When I add the `secondImageView` to my view (`[self.view addSubview:secondImageView];`) the first one disappears.

The `firstImageView` has the following frame:

X: 114.0
Y: 192.0
Width: 93.0
Height: 142.0

Why does this keep happening?

So I kind of fixed it. I added the secondImageView in the InterfaceBuilder with the same frame and stuff and now it works.

Comment: could you show some screenshot?? And just comment out the line where you change the frame for firstImageView, and try again if it is still there or not. If yes, then there is a problem with your frame.

Comment: It actually happens before I change the frame of the firstImageView. It happens at this line: [self.view addSubview:secondImageView];
If I comment this line out, the first one does not disappear, but the second one does not appear.. which is clear.

Comment: so without adding the secondImageView, the new frame set inside the animation for firstImageView is working. Right?

Comment: I used the same code of yours. But it is working good.

Comment: I solved it with a different way

Comment: Ok. But the problem could be in alpha or opaque in your code. Check if that is correct if you get a problem again like this.

Comment: A screenshot will be really helpful as @DineshRaja was suggesting. Just make sure that your secondImageView is not in front of your firstImageView. If that is the case, you could call bringSubviewToFront to put the fistImageView in front.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove any subview from view just add

[self.view removeSubview:obj_name];

or if you wanna change image for image view

change directly,

firstImageView.image = //set image;

Comment: How it is related to OP question? can you elaborate me? and also I haven't heard about any method like `removeSubview:` I think you mistaken the `removeFromSuperView` method

Comment: This was not the question... My firstImageView disappears after adding the second one.